# External hard drive and Xbox

Tags: external-hard-drive, nas, media, xbox360, playback

Is there any way of playing movies on the Xbox from an external hard drive?

Comment: questions about interfacing a game console to another computer for media playback are fine.  questions about connecting a hard-drive to an Xbox via, say, USB, are not.  since this doesn't specify i'm inclined to reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. Use a DLNA server to expose those files. One example may be a machine with Windows Media Center. Another (which is what I'm using) is a NAS server. All my media files are available to my Xbox 360.

Comment: what OS are you running on your NAS server? what software provides the DLNA services?  details are good. :)

Comment: I'm using a D-Link DNS 323. It comes with a version of Linux and a DLNA server pre-installed. The internet is full of hacks, allowing you to run whatever you want on it, if you don't like the original (which works great for me).

Answer (score 0):

Directly plugging a usb hard drive into the Xbox if it is under 512GB and in FAT32 will play video formats in "system video player".